# Message sent but not delivered in whatsapp PHP API

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am using whats app API https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

But When I am trying  to send message with this api

Then I am getting the status `{"success":true,"data":"Message Sent!","messages":null}`

But the message is not delivered to inbox

I have tried with `number without 0 or country code`, `with 0` and `with country code`

But not delivered the message